# Oracle Error in date format

Tags: date, oracle11g

I have a query like this

```
SELECT ITEM_CODE FROM my_table WHERE JOB_DATE BETWEEN

 CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE(:ST_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')) = EXTRACT ( MONTH FROM TO_DATE(:END_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')) THEN TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(:ST_DATE,-1),'DD/MM/YYYY')

   WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE(:ST_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')) != EXTRACT ( MONTH FROM TO_DATE(:END_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')) THEN   TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(:ST_DATE,-1),'MONTH'),'DD/MM/YYYY') END 

   AND

CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE(:ST_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')) = EXTRACT ( MONTH FROM TO_DATE(:END_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')) THEN     TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(:END_DATE,-1),'DD/MM/YYYY')

    WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE(:ST_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')) != EXTRACT ( MONTH FROM TO_DATE(:END_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')) THEN TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(:ST_DATE,-1)),'DD/MM/YYYY') END
```

I am entering the date in the default format as 'dd-mon-yyyy' and want to display 'DD/MM/YYYY' in the report.
But this gives me error as

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

in the table Job_date is stored as DATE type. What can i do to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function

```
TO_DATE(:ST_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

tries to convert string :st_date into date using specified format 'DD/MM/YYYY'. If you are entering the date in another format ('dd-mon-yyyy'), you get ORA-01843. To avoid this error and still display the date in desired format
use 'DD-MON-YYYY' in TO_DATE function and 'DD/MM/YYYY' in TO_CHAR function

Also

```
ADD_MONTHS(:ST_DATE, -1)
```

will try to convert :st_date implicitly into date using your session settings. I would suggest using explicit conversion:

```
ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:ST_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY'),-1)
```